# TimePicker Dialog not showing AM PM selected Color

Tags: android, timepicker, android-timepicker

I am developing an alarm clock in which time picker dialog is working correctly however the AM and PM selected color is not shown. After selecting an hour and minute the time picker dialog doesn't give an option to select or AM or PM. However, if I clicked on AM and PM then it is selected but no color has been shown. What is the reason behind that? How can I make sure that time picker dialog also gives an option to select AM or PM?
Please note that I have to use the 12-hour format for this.
Here is my code:

```
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    final int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    final int min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    TimePickerDialog picker = new TimePickerDialog(getContext(),R.style.MyTimePickerDialogStyle,
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker tp, int sHour, int sMinute) {
                        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                        AlarmData alarm = getAlarmio().newAlarm();
                        alarm.time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, sHour);
                        alarm.time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, sMinute);
                        alarm.setTime(getAlarmio(), manager, alarm.time.getTimeInMillis());
                        alarm.setEnabled(getContext(), manager, true);
                        getAlarmio().onAlarmsChanged();
                }
            }, hour, min, false);
    picker.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.colorNightForeground);
    picker .show();
```

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. Have u found a solution?

Comment: Sadly Not yet. :(